# Returning setof derived from for loop in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql

I have the below function.  It is intended to loop through every schema and return all user IDs from a table in that schema.  The schemas have the format: users[0-100].

```
$body$
declare
  r varchar;           
  sql text := 'select userid from $1.users';
begin
  for r in select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ~ '^users'
  loop
    return query select format('select userid from %s.users', r);
  end loop;
  return;
end
$body$
```

I have tried a few different ways, but I haven't been able to return a set.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you're returning the text of queries to the caller instead of executing them and returning their results.

Comment: @DanielVérité - Thanks.  How can I return the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
return query select format('select userid from %s.users', r);
```

returns the text of queries to the caller instead of executing them and returning their results. You want a three-steps operation: build-execute-return.

These steps are easier to figure out if the code is broken into two lines (assuming `query_text` is a text variable declared above):

```
query_text := format('select userid from %I.users', r);
return query execute query_text;
```

Note: I've also changed `%s` to `%I`, the specifier dedicated to identifiers. If the schema identifier required quoting, it would happen automatically, whereas with `%s` the query would fail.